# How to parametrize different numbers or positions of arguments?

Tags: python, testing, pytest

For example, say I have two functions:

```py
def func3(a, b, c):
    for var in (a, b, c):
        if var < 0:
            raise ValueError
    pass


def func7(a, b, c, d, e, f, g):
    for var in (a, b, c, d, e, f, g):
        if var < 0:
            raise ValueError
    pass
```

And in my tests, I want to test a set of invalid values at each parameter.  The only way I know of to do this is to write them all out:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize('val', [-2, -3, -4.5])
def test_invalid_param(val):
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        func3(val, 0, 0)
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        func3(0, val, 0)
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        func3(0, 0, val)
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        func7(val, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        func7(0, val, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        func7(0, 0, val, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    ...
```

How can I combine these all into one `with pytest.raises` case?

If both funcs had the same number of arguments, I could stack this:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize('func', [func3, func7])
```

but they don't.  If they just had different numbers of arguments and I was only testing the first, then I could stack this:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize('func, args', [(func3, (0, 0)), 
                                        (func7, (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))])
```

But that won't work for testing the parametrized value in multiple positions.

Comment: Maybe test each function separately?

Comment: @IainShelvington Ok, but that would have even more repetition?

Comment: a little repetition is desirable when it helps simplify or clarify your code. Parametrizing the test so that you completely eliminate repetition is going to make the test hard to understand and complex

Comment: Would [decorators](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/) help your use case?  I might be misunderstanding something but this looks like something where a decorator could be written to do your validation and then your unit tests can focus on the stuff that's unique to each function

Comment: @IainShelvington *If* there's no simpler way to represent it without repetition, then yes, I agree

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind increasing the number of tests you can use the values sets as a parameter to the test. Each set will be a different test

```
def data_source():
    for val in [-2, -3, -4.5]:
        for values_set in [[val, 0, 0], [0, val, 0], [0, 0, val], [val, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, val, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, val, 0, 0, 0, 0]]:
            yield values_set


def func(values):
for var in values:
    if var < 0:
        raise ValueError
pass


@pytest.mark.parametrize('values', data_source())
def test_invalid_param(values):
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        func(values)
```

In case of failure the stack trace will look like

```
(test_invalid_param[values6])
values = [3, 0, 0]

    @pytest.mark.parametrize('values', data_source())
    def test_invalid_param(values):
        with pytest.raises(ValueError):
>           func(*values)
E           Failed: DID NOT RAISE <class 'ValueError'>

Example_test.py:32: Failed
```

As a side note, to allow different number of arguments you can use `*` in the parameter

```
def func(*values):
    for var in values:
        if var < 0:
            raise ValueError
    pass
```